# Generate random values based on a seed Swift 3

Tags: swift, random

lets say you were making a game and this game has procedurally generated terrain from a seed that the user inputted in his world-creation menu

and this seed generates a set of values that only change if the seed changes

for instance lets say you want to get a random set of integers to generate in a for-loop and pull randomly from an array the set of integers stay the same every time and pull the same items from the array in the exact same order every time you run the for-loop until you change the seed

how would one achieve this in swift

in my code here i can get the terrain to spawn in but it does not generate the same every time which is what i am trying to get it to do

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let tile1 = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "stone") ,size: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))
    let tile2 = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "water") ,size: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))
    let tile3 = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "sand") ,size: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))
    let tile4 = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "grass") ,size: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))

    let tileGroup1 = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tile1)
    let tileGroup2 = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tile2)
    let tileGroup3 = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tile3)
    let tileGroup4 = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tile4)
    let tileGroup5 = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tile4)
    let tileGroup6 = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tile4)

    let tileSet = SKTileSet(tileGroups: [tileGroup1,tileGroup2,tileGroup3,tileGroup4,tileGroup5,tileGroup6])

    let columns = 5
    let rows = 5

    let tileSize = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)

    //this is another GKNoise class called Noise
    let noise = Noise()
    let noiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise, size: vector_double2(10.0,10.0), origin: vector_double2(0.0,0.0), sampleCount: vector_int2(100), seamless: true)
    //this is another SKTileMapNode Class called TileMap and a class func called tileMapNodes
    let tileMap = TileMap.tileMapNodes(tileSet: tileSet, columns: columns, rows: rows, tileSize: tileSize, from: noiseMap, tileTypeNoiseMapThresholds: [(-1.0 as NSNumber),(+1.0 as NSNumber)])

    tileMapNode = tileMap.first!

    let seed = Int

    for column in 0 ..< tileMapNode.numberOfColumns {
        for row in 0 ..< tileMapNode.numberOfRows {
            let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tileSet.tileGroups.count)))
            print(rand)
            let tile = tileMapNode.tileSet.tileGroups[rand]
            tileMapNode.setTileGroup(tile, forColumn: column, row: row)
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you write already some code? pls post it - then we can give you some hints

Comment: Take a look at this answer.  It provides the seed behavior you need.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679898/1630618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a random value based on a specific seed use: `srand48` and `drand48`:

srand allow you to specify the seed:

```
    srand48(230)
```

Then drand48 will give you a double between 0 and 1:

```
    let doubleValue = drand48()
```

So in your case, if you want an Int between 0 and 9, you can do something like:

```
    srand48(230)
    print("Random number: \(1 + Int((drand48() * 8) + 0.5))")
    print("Random number: \(1 + Int((drand48() * 8) + 0.5))")
    print("Random number: \(1 + Int((drand48() * 8) + 0.5))")
```

It will give you the 3 pseudo random numbers until you change the seed

Here is the `drand48` applied to your new question:

```
let seed = srand48(230)

for column in 0 ..< tileMapNode.numberOfColumns {
    for row in 0 ..< tileMapNode.numberOfRows {
        let rand = Int(Double(tileSet.tileGroups.count) * drand48() - 0.5)
        print(rand)
        let tile = tileMapNode.tileSet.tileGroups[rand]
        tileMapNode.setTileGroup(tile, forColumn: column, row: row)
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! thanks alot! is there anyway to get it to generate a random number in a for-loop that i can use to pull data randomly from an array?

Comment: i need it to generate the same numbers over and over again until i change the seed because the code is counting the columns/rows and randomly setting a texture pulled randomly from an array

Comment: also its giving me an error `Constant 'seed' inferred to have type 'Void', which may be unexpected` how to fix?

Comment: could you re-read my question i changed it to what i originally meant

Comment: I updated my answer but I think its better to avoid to change your question :)

Comment: i had trouble with the section of code `let rand = Int((drand48() * tileSet.tileGroups.count) - 0.5)` saying *operand * could not be applied to Int and Double* but changing that bit to `let rand = Int(Double(tileSet.tileGroups.count) * drand48() - 0.5)` solves all the issues (btw i would recommend changing your answer with the code corrected so that future readers can get the correct answer)

Comment: Yep, I forgot to switch the value to double, you are right!